# Validating a CSV File

Tags: java, excel, csv

I am using `CSVReader` for reading CSV files in my project.
I am facing a issue like in my CSV File Reader if a user is uploading `xls` file (i.e. file renamed from `Company.xlsx` to `Company.csv`) than it is neither throwing an exception nor I am able to figure out how to validate that the file is CSV or Excel with just `.csv` ext. 
I tried with `Files.probeContentType` but no use as the value for Excel and CSV is application/vnd.ms-excel

Thanks in advance.

====Code=====

```
try
{ 
Path source = Paths.get("D:\\Employee_detail2.xls"); 
System.out.println("Content type :"+Files.probeContentType(source)); 

CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(new FileReader("D:\\Employee_detail2.xls"), ','); 
List<String[]> allRows = reader.readAll(); 
System.out.println("Content :"); 
for(String[] row : allRows){ 
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(row)); } 
}
catch (Exception e)
{
System.out.println(e.toString());
}
```

Comment: Could you include the relevant code? It'd make your problem easier to troubleshoot.

Comment: Edit the question and add it there so you get the formatting.